# using imaplib to fetch only the headers of the emails?

Tags: python, imaplib

Hi i was wondering if someone can help me on extracting the headers of my emails in gmail. I have this code:

```
import imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4('imap.gmail.com')
M.login('myusername', 'mypassword')
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
M.close()
M.logout()
```

However, i only want to pull out the headers of each email, not the body? Can anyone sort me out please as i have no idea?

Answer (score 22):

In your example you would do this:

```
typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')
```

Here is the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

Comment: Ty, sorry that OP never selected this as the right answer.

Comment: ty. Very helpful answer.